# Is it possible to save & retrieve the data filled in HTML form to/from xml file stored locally on PC?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, local-storage

I've recently made an HTML form to fill some service reports & now want to save & retrieve them on/from PC itself (preferably in xml format) (**not on server**).

I'hv checked it on w3scools /on this page too but still I couldn't get the desired solution.

Could you please inform me the possible ways to make it happen.

Comment: You tagged the question with local storage, can you use that?

Comment: Are we talking about automated process without human interactions or does user can upload this file?

Comment: Use javascript to create an xml from the html form. Save the content to a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), send it to the user with [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/File) api and [getAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/File#getAsDataURL())

Comment: @WisdmLabs there are a number of (vendor specific) local storage databases one could use not just cookies.

Comment: If you want this for an local application (i.e. not hosted on a server at all) you can try to access the browser's extended APIs (the ones used by plugins) which do have access to files on the user's machine.

Comment: @David - HI, by the term local storage i wanted to say storing a file on PC itself.. i'm not working for any server client prog. It is simply to fill the report form & to save it on pc itself & later to email.

Comment: @Justinas - yes, use will have to upload a file

Comment: @adi: That's what local storage is.  It's a browser-owned data store accessible by JavaScript.  It has nothing to do with server-side code, which is why they call it "local" storage.

Comment: @Mihai Stancu - hi, you got me right, i want this to be totally a local application loading & saving data file from PC itself. Is browser's extended API's helpful for this application ? If yes, please give me some more info abt using them.. & the corresponding reference to study more..

Comment: @David - ok, then we are on same track .. do u have any method to accomplish this .. with the ActiveX Object I'm getting access denied error. For me it is perfectly fine to have this application worked only on internet explorer...

Comment: The documentation for creating plugins for any major browser should be your starting point. If you don't want to create a plugin perhaps user scripts would be useful instead (there's a plugin that runs javascript files you wrote with access to the plugin-level API).

Comment: @adi: Well, you could start with the local storage documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage  I'm not sure what you're trying to do with ActiveX, or why.  But if you're getting an error then you can always ask a Stack Overflow question about it.

Comment: @David- Hi, I finally succeded in creating & writting xml file with the help of blob in HTML5 & local storage. Now I need one more help in reading the xml node values & re-assigning it to a specific field in the html form . I've added this as another question. can u please help me with this ?http://stackoverflow.com/q/32554144/5235096?sgp=2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you want to store the data on the user's computer, is that right? 
Then it would be the best to create an XML file and force download to user's computer.

(I'm using jQuery because it's fastest)

STEP 1: make an ajax request.

```
    function downloadFormData(form){
        var formData= $(form).serialize(); //form is an DOM element - the form you want to retrieve data from
        $.ajax({
            url:"save.php",
            data: formData,
            success: function (file) {
                window.location.href =  "download.php?path="+ file
            }
        });   
    }
```

2) Create a php file, name it as save.php with the following content in your root directory:

```
    <?php
    $xml_string = "<?xml version etc.?><data>";
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        $xml_string.='<'.$key.'>'.$value.'</'.$key.'>';
    $xml_string.='</data>
    $file = 'formData.xml';




    // save to file
    file_put_contents('./'.$file, $xml_string);

    // return the filename
    echo $file; exit;
```

5) Create a php file, name it as download.php with the following content in your root directory

```
<?php
$file = 'formData.xml'
// $file = trim($_GET['path']); if you use download.php for anything else

// force user to download the file
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/xml');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    unlink($file);
    exit;
}
else {
    echo "$file not found";
}
```

I hope you understand the way this works, because you definetly can't leave everything like that (then users could download any file they wanted), but i hope my answer will help you.

**EDIT**:
a PURE javascript solution

```
function createXMLandDownload(form){
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = "MyXml.xml"; //downloaded file name
    a.addEventListener("click" , function (){
        var xmlstring = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><data>';
        $(form).find(":input").each(function(){
            xmlstring+="<"+this.name+">"+this.value+"</"+this.name+">";
        }
        xmlstring+="</data>";
        document.open('data:Application/octet-stream,' + encodeURIComponent(xmlstring ));
    });
    a.click();
}
```

Comment: Hello Luka, thank u very much for help but, here i would like to avoid using php or any othre way ( as I m new to web development field) is it possible to do with html & javascript ?

Comment: it is all ok, just copy my code, it is all ready, and as simple as posible, and don't vory, i don't understand all of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can examine the Javascript behind this application (http://www.cloudformatter.com/Nimbus) like this page here:

[Sample Nimbus Invoice](http://www.cloudformatter.com/nimbus.Editor?http://cdn.xportability.com/Samples/Invoice.html)

This code shows (1) data in the editor area being saved to local storage constantly, (2) option to make a pseudo HTML/XML file and download to disk (Save to ... Disk), (3) option to make that same package and save to storage on the web (New Nimble, Save Nimble). I am not going to go through all the code, the most relevant is here below for saving locally to disk a package stored in the variable "archive":

```
function SaveFile(archive) {
var textToBLOB = new Blob([archive.innerHTML], { type: 'text/xml' });
var sFileName = 'varypackage.html';
var newLink = document.createElement('a');
newLink.download = sFileName;
if (window.webkitURL !== null) {
  newLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
}
else {
  newLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToBLOB);
  newLink.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(newLink);
}
newLink.click();
```

}

Look here for all the code (which contains much more that just the saving/loading but it is in here): http://www.cloudformatter.com/Resources/pages/varyhtml/script/02_control.js