# reading the contents of blob in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, html, blob

Finally  I succeeded in creating an xml file locally & downloading it on a pc using JavaScript & BLOB in HTML 5. (as shown in code below).

This file can be stored as a text or as xml type. 
now  my  question is how to open this file (again from local disk in PC) using JavaScript & load the values of a particular node to a respective field in HTML form. ??

can  anyone please help me with this ?

// to save the contents :

```
  function savedata() {

            var feederdocument = document.createElement("FeederDocument");
            var feederreport = document.createElement("FeederReport");
            if (document.getElementById("feederserialnumber").value == '') {
                alert('Please Enter the Serial Number')
            }
            else {

                var fileextns = '.xml';

                if (fileextns == '.xml') {
                    var xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
                }
                else {
                    var xmlString = '';
                }

                var orderdata = document.createElement("OrderData");

                orderdata.appendChild(document.createElement("ClientName"));


                orderdata.appendChild(document.createElement("ContactPerson"));
                orderdata.appendChild(document.createElement("Country"));
                orderdata.appendChild(document.createElement("Designation"));
                orderdata.appendChild(document.createElement("Reference"));
                orderdata.appendChild(document.createElement("Department"));
                orderdata.appendChild(document.createElement("OrderNumber"));
                orderdata.appendChild(document.createElement("PhoneNumber"));
                orderdata.appendChild(document.createElement("SpecialistName"));
                orderdata.appendChild(document.createElement("MobileNumber"));
                orderdata.appendChild(document.createElement("Duration"));
                orderdata.appendChild(document.createElement("Emailid"));

                feederreport.appendChild(orderdata);
                feederdocument.appendChild(feederreport);
```

// For Downloading the contents in xml format; I'm using blob as shown :

```
var res = xmlString.concat(feederdocument.innerHTML);
            var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([res], { type: 'text/html' });
            var fileNameToSaveAs = (document.getElementById("feederserialnumber").value).concat(fileextns);

            var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
            downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
            downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
            if (window.webkitURL != null) {

                downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
            }
            else {

                downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
                downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
                downloadLink.style.display = "none";
                document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
            }

            downloadLink.click();
        }
        function destroyClickedElement(event) {
            document.body.removeChild(event.target);
        }
```

Comment: Please check formatting of your code and try to ask one question per post. (Note that likely your sample code can be made significantly shorter to just focus on one problem at a time).

Comment: @ Alexi - thanks for bringing it to my notice..  Necessary corrections done

Comment: it's not possible to do what you want - not sure how the code you posted is at all relevant, it works, and it has nothing to do with the issue. Showing some random code isn't the same as showing code you are having a problem with

Comment: @ Jaromanda X this is the part of the code ( which is still working); as I said before I'm able to generate a valid xml file for the contents of my srevice report form. IF you can please help me with the reading the contents of blob & assigning the values of node to particular field, will help me a lot or rather please let mee know what other clarifications do you need?- thanks